# regrouping an array of object by a property of the object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects (`Employee {role: string, members: string []}`)

```js
array = [{
  role: 'doctor',
  fullName: 'x'
}, {
  role: 'nurse',
  fullName: 'y'
}, {
  role: 'doctor',
  fullName: 'z'
}]
```

and I want to group objects by role in a new array (result) in typescript

```js
result = [{
    role: 'doctor',
    members: ['x', 'z']
  } {
    role: 'nurse',
    members: ['y']
  }
}
```

My code:

```js
result = array.map(function(pemp: any) {

  if (!array.some(function(el: any) {
    return el.role === pemp.role;
  })) {
    return new Employee(pemp.role, pemp.fullName);
  } else {
    var pos = this.result.map(function(e: any) {
      return e.role;
    }).indexOf(pemp.role);
    this.result[pos].members.push(pemp.fullName)
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a javascript array of objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: I think it's not typescript issue. It's about your coding javascript skill.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
var data = [{
  role: 'doctor',
  fullName: 'x'
}, {
  role: 'nurse',
  fullName: 'y'
}, {
  role: 'doctor',
  fullName: 'z'
}];

var obj = {};
data.forEach(function(item){
  if(!obj[item.role]) obj[item.role] = [];
  obj[item.role].push(item.fullName);
});

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k){
  return {role:k, members: obj[k]}
});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result,0,4)
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a solution in typescript, you could use a single loop with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a temporary object as reference to the result array for grouped roles.

```js
var array = [{ role: 'doctor', fullName: 'x' }, { role: 'nurse', fullName: 'y' }, { role: 'doctor', fullName: 'z' }],
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.role]) {
        this[a.role] = { role: a.role, members: [] };
        result.push(this[a.role]);
    }
    this[a.role].members.push(a.fullName);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for your explication!! I converted your solution in Typescript but it still not working. I am still blocked :(

Comment: i am sorry, i have no clue about typescript.

Comment: Your help is very appreciated. Thanks Nina :)